# how to self-discover variables within groovy script?

Tags: groovy, discovery, scriptengine, groovyshell

the scenario is, i can write groovy code that will be executed by a script engine within another application.

the only thing i know is the function name and it takes one argument, for example:

def runGroovyCode(name1) { ... }

is there a way to figure out from within the groovy code itself, what other variable or objects (other than the name1 passed in) that is available to be used by the groovy code?

hope i described this clearly.  it's kind of like the groovy code self-discovering what external variables (data) are within it's scope.

basically, i need more data for my groovy code.  and i need to confirm, if name1 is the only data i have, or maybe there are more variables available, but i don't know what their names are otherwise i cannot access them.

i need to find out what variables or objects are available in this scripting engine execution environment that my groovy code will be running within.

there is no further documentation.  so basically, my groovy code is running in a black box.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at [`groovy.lang.Script`](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/src/main/groovy/lang/Script.java) class. It has a property called `binding` which contains all the variables that have been passed to the script.

Here is an example

```
class Main {
    def static SCRIPT = """
            // binding var contains all the bindings of the script
            println binding.variables
        """

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        def factory = new ScriptEngineManager();
        def engine = factory.getEngineByName("groovy");
        engine.eval(SCRIPT, new SimpleBindings([param1: 1, param2: 2]));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[param1:1, param2:2, context:javax.script.SimpleScriptContext@2f7c2f4f, out:java.io.PrintWriter@6af93788]
```